# Decouple django admin inline in different apps

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to decouple 2 apps, so far I've decouple different parts of the implementation. However I'm stuck when decoupling the *django-admin*. The dependency between apps must be clear, (i.e. *NO circular dependency* should exist in these apps). Yet, the *usability* of the system should not be compromised badly.

## Scenario

In a book library system, **catalog** app and **holding** app has been decoupled, where **catalog** only concern with the bibliographic cataloging while **holding** is concern with the library owned book.

#### Models:

- `catalog.Book` is the model for book information
- `holding.BookCopy` is the model for physical copy of the book.

A `Book` has many `BookCopy`, while a `BookCopy` belongs to a `Book`.

It is also clear that **holding** apps must depends on **catalog**, but **catalog** should not depends on **holding**.

#### Admin:

```
# File: catalog/admin.py
from holding import models as holding_models
# ...

class BookCopyInline(TabularInline):
    model = holding_models.BookCopy

class BookAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Book
    inlines = [BookCopyInline]

admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

> Problem: catalog admin has dependencies with holding models, making it an unnecessary dependency in reverse direction. (catalog app should not depends on holding, but holding can depends on catalog)

## Try 1:

Move `BookCopyInline` into **holding/admin.py**.

```
# File: catalog/admin.py
from holding import admin as holding_admin

class BookAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Book
    inlines = [holding_admin.BookCopyInline]

admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)

# File: holding/admin.py
class BookCopyInline(TabularInline):
    model = BookCopy
```

> Still has circular app dependencies, but instead of depending on the model, we only depends on the holding.admin. which is better, but not fully decoupled yet.

Comment: I've solved the problem, it is now fully decoupled, no circular dependency. I'll update the possible answer later :)

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution to this problem is to add the inlines in the holding module and re-register the ModelAdmin inside the holding module.

```
# File: catalog/admin.py
class BookAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Book

# File: holding/admin.py
from catalog.admin import BookAdmin

class BookCopyInline(TabularInline):
    model = BookCopy
BookAdmin.inlines.append(BookCopyInline)

admin.site.unregister(BookAdmin)
admin.site.register(catalog_models.Book, catalog_admin.BookAdmin)
```

Comment: This works. Furthermore, it's not necessary to unregister and register the `Book` admin.